# Wordpress keep refresh WP_Option Cache breaks the site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

The website is running with wordpress and woocommerce. Recently I met a problem that the mysql always stuck and has 100+ connections. With further look I can see it's because wordpress is sending

```
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes'
```

which cost mysql at least 20 seconds to run and locked the table. At the same time, a lots of select query for a specific value in wp_options just came in so all these queries are open and waiting.

I think its because the way wordpress call get_options() is finding from cache and then if cache cannot find it, it will read from database which pulling everything.

But I don't understand why wordpress calling this every minute?

Now wordpress call the queries below every minute or less which just killing my website.

```
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes'
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'uninstall_plugins' LIMIT 1
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = '_transient_timeout_w3tc.verify_plugins' LIMIT 1
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = '_transient_w3tc.verify_plugins' LIMIT 1
```

It actually calling almost 20 queries which I didn't list all of them.

I guess everytime something calling get_option() lead a sets of calls to find everything from wp_option table. As I can see there are 30 queries of

```
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes'
```

calling while I am typing this question.

And I can see from slow query log:

```
Query_time: 201.573018 Lock_time: 27.904311 Rows_sent: 9456 Rows_examined: 9456
SET timestamp=1525462712;
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes';
```

Did anyone has any idea what is causing this problem? I tried to add index to autoload but it still can kill my site with 30 repeat calls.

Things I checked:
I enabled the firewall so I it shouldn't be DDos attack, but I really thinking if there is existing wordpress/woocommerce bug can cause this issue by a simple post/get request.
Checked the cron jobs running background has nothing wrong.

Thank you everyone in advance. This problem is killing me since I really don't know where should I start to look at this issue.